# Bandpass Filter for 4D image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, lowpass-filter, highpass-filter

I have implemented in Matlab a bandpass filter for a 4D image (4D matrix). The first three dimensions are spatial dimensions, the last dimension is a temporal one. Here is the code:

```
function bandpass_img = bandpass_filter(img)
% Does bandpass filtering on input image
%
% Input:
%   img: 4D image
%
% Output:
%   bandpass_img: Bandpass filtered image

TR = 1; % Repetition time
n_vols = size(img,3);
X = [];

% Create matrix (voxels x time points)
for z = 1:size(img,3)
    for y = 1:size(img,2)
        for x = 1:size(img,1)
            X = [X; squeeze(img(x,y,z,:))']; %#ok<AGROW>
        end
    end
end

Fs = 1/TR;
nyquist = 0.5*Fs;

% Pass bands
F = [0.01/nyquist, 0.1/nyquist];
type = 'bandpass';

% Filter order
n = floor(n_vols/3.5);

% Ensure filter order is odd for bandpass
if (mod(n,2) ~= 0), n=n+1; end
fltr = fir1(n, F, type);

% Looking at frequency response
% freqz(fltr)

% Store plot to file
% set(gcf, 'Color', 'w');
% export_fig('freq_response', '-png', '-r100');

% Apply to image
X = filter(fltr, 1, X);

% Reconstructing image
i = 1;
bandpass_img = zeros(size(img));
for z = 1:size(img,3)
    for y = 1:size(img,2)
        for x = 1:size(img,1)
            bandpass_img(x,y,z,:) = X(i,:)';
            i = i + 1;
        end
    end
end

end
```

I'm not sure if the implementation is correct. Could somebody verify it or does somebody find a failure?

**Edit:** Thanks to SleuthEye it now kind of works when I'm using `bandpass_img = filter(fltr, 1, img, [], 4);`. But there is still a minor problem. My images are of size 80x35x12x350, i.e. there are 350 time points. I have plotted the average time series before and after applying the bandpass filter.

Before bandpass filtering:

[image: before bandpass]

After bandpass filtering:

[image: after bandpass]

**Why is this peak at the very beginning of the filtered image?**

**Edit 2**: There is now a peak at the beginning and at the end. See:

[image]

I have made a second plot where I marked each point with a *. See:

[image]

So the first and last two time points seem to be lower.

It seems that I have to remove 2 time points at the beginning and also 2 time points at the end, so in total I will loose 4 time points.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering a concatenation of all the elements using the 1-D `filter` function as you are doing is likely going to result in a distorted image as the smoothing makes the end of each row blend into the beginning of the next one. Unless you are trying to obtain a psychedelic rendition of your 4D data, this is unlikely to do what you are expecting it to.

Now, according to [Matlab's filter documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html):

> `y = filter(b,a,x,zi,dim)` acts along dimension `dim`. For example, if `x` is a matrix, then `filter(b,a,x,zi,2)` returns the filtered data for each row.

So, to smooth out the 3D images over time (which you indicated is the fourth dimension of you matrix `img`), you should use

```
bandpass_img = filter(fltr, 1, img, [], 4);
```

Used as such, the signal would starts a 0 because that's the default initial state of the filter and the filter takes a few samples to ramp up. If you know the value of the initial state you can specify that with the `zi` argument (the 4th argument):

```
bandpass_img = filter(fltr, 1, img, zi, 4);
```

Otherwise, a typical order `N` linear FIR filter has a delay of `N/2` samples. To get rid of the initial ramp up you can thus just discard those `N/2` initial samples:

```
bandpass_img = bandpass_img(:,:,:,(N/2+1):end);
```

Similarly, if you want to see the output corresponding to the last `N/2` input values, you'd have to pad your input with `N/2` extra samples (zeros will do):

```
img = padarray(img, [0 0 0 N/2], 0, 'post');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your extended explanation. For me the zi argument is not that clear. Which initial state is meant?

Comment: By the way, N is odd in my case, that means I'm getting N by `N = floor(n_vols/3.5); if (mod(N,2) ~= 0), N=N+1; end`. Should I round N/2 down or up?

Comment: You'll typically know the initial state as the final state output of a previous filter operation when you chain filtering of blocks of data (e.g. `[bandpass_img, zi] = filtrer(fltr,1,img, zi, 4)`). For the delay it's usually more convenient to use `N` even so you wind up with an integer delay. But if you must use odd `N` then for the rounding, since you are trying to avoid the ramp up artefact at the start of the sequence I'd round up (but round down to avoid the ramp down artefact due to zero padding at the end of the sequence).

Comment: I don't have to use odd N, I have just read that for bandpass it is preferred. Would you recommend to use just `N = floor(n_vols/3.5);` without rounding to odd value? Second, if I round up at the start but round down at the end, I will probably loosing one time point compared to original image, right?

Comment: I've more typically seen even filters order `N` (which result in an odd number of coefficients), including bandpass, since they have integer delays. Indeed rounding up at start but down at the end will result in one less time point if using an odd `N` (another reason to choose even `N`), to be sure you don't have any artefact (you could round the same way at the start and end if you can afford a small amount of artefact).

Comment: I have `N = floor(n_vols/3.5) = 3`. So I could use either N = 4 or N = 2. Is there a disadvantage (or remarkable difference in result) if using even number? And would you either recommend to use N=4 or N=2?

Comment: By the way, the image is 80x35x12x350 and I used n_vols = 12.

Comment: I have found an additional thing. Something is going wrong with `img = padarray(img, [size(img,1) size(img,2) size(img,3) size(img,4)+N/2]);`. It turns my 80 x 35 x 12 x 350 image into 240 x 105 x 36 x 1054.

Comment: My bad, should have been `padarray(img, [0 0 0 N/2], 0, 'post')` which would add 2 points at the end of `img`. Then to remove 2 point from the beginning of `bandpass_img` you should use `bandpass_img(:,:,:,(N/2+1):end)`

Comment: There is still a problem. I have updated my post, see edit 2.

Comment: As you probably noticed the relative deviation at the beginning and end is much less than your original plot, which is probably as best as one could hope for without removing more samples and without knowing the previous & next values while filtering a block of data. As for the value of `N`, I see no particular reason for it to be tied to `n_vols` (other than perhaps some application specific constraints which you haven't indicated).